# Which algorithms can be used to generate a euclidean embedding for a manifold given a pairwise distance matrix of geodesics?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, matrix, scikit-learn

I have a square matrix `D` (currently represented as a numpy array of shape (572, 572)) plausibly corresponding to pairwise distances between points along the surface of a roughly cylindrical object. I.e., the value `D[i,j]` corresponds to the minimal length of any path along the surface of that hollow cylinder. How do I construct a 3-dimensional (or n-dimensional) embedding of those 572 points into euclidean space which preserves those **geodesic** distances?

### Current Attempts

Algorithms like [locally linear embedding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#locally-linear-embedding) and [isomap](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/manifold.html#isomap) are able to take that matrix of pairwise geodesic distances and output an embedding so that the pairwise **euclidean** distances are the same as the original geodesics. While this is not the same task in general, in the case where the output happens to approximate a hypercube in some dimension the desired transformation has actually happened (consider the [swiss roll](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/manifold/plot_swissroll.html)) since the embedding is itself a manifold, so euclidean distance corresponds to geodesic distance.

This is not the case for even slightly more complicated objects like cylinders. By treating geodesic distances as euclidean, antipodal points on the desired cylinder are mapped to locations much further from each other than desired, and the corresponding global optimization problem will often result in a branching structure with ends of the branches corresponding to maximally distant antipodal points, amplifying small perturbations in the random sampling of the cylinder. In general, naive applications of these algorithms doesn't seem to solve the problem at hand.

Another somewhat fruitful (though expensive) approach has been a brute **monte carlo** technique. I generate random samples from tubelike objects with varying parameters till I find a set of parameters generating geodesic distance matrices similar to mine, up to a permutation (which is dealt with not too inefficiently by solving the linear system converting that distance matrix to mine and testing to see if the result is near a permutation matrix). Then a near-optimal mapping from my 572 points onto that object preserving pairwise distances is performed by finding the nearest permutation matrix to the aforementioned near-permutation matrix.

This is yielding plausible results, but it presupposes the shape of the data and is horrendously expensive. I've performed some of the more obvious optimizations like working with small random samples instead of the entire data set and using gradient-based techniques for parameter estimation, but a more general-purpose technique would be nice.

### Caveats

This problem of course does not have a unique solution. Even assuming that manifolds can be unambiguously identified in 3-space from a finite uniform sampling, just squishing a cylinder yields a shape with the same geodesics and different euclidean distances (hence a different embedding). This does not bother me any more than LLE and Isomap yielding differing solutions, and I would be fine with any plausible answer.

With regards to uniquely identifying manifolds from a finite sample, for the sake of argument I would be fine just using the `dist_matrix_` attribute from a fitted `Isomap` class from the `scikit-learn` package without any special parameters to find the geodesics. That performs an unnecessary `MDS` step, but it isn't terribly expensive, and it works out of the box. We would then like an embedding which minimizes the frobenius distance between the original geodesic distance matrix and the `dist_matrix_` attribute.

Comment: There probably more help on this at  https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://gis.stackexchange.com/&ved=2ahUKEwis0dnuhL3bAhXhBZoKHVT5DmkQFjAAegQICRAB&usg=AOvVaw03mkCgwRTnCEJMf8v_qGf9

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Their [help section](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) indicates that this would not be an allowed question. Would you ask over there anyway?

Comment: which part of the rules seems prohibitive? you question counts as geodesic, the only change can be is to omit the python and ask about algorithm

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak Of the 5 allowed topics they [reference](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), the only one that seems applicable is **geodesy**. However, geodesy is an earth science, and it isn't obvious to me that geodesics on arbitrary manifolds should be considered as part of geodesy, which only considers pseudo spheroidal manifolds. Even then, in the context of geodesy the shape of the manifold is known ahead of time, so this question in particular seems to be out of scope. Would they welcome it anyway?

Comment: You mention a “finite uniform sampling”—is there some structure in your point set?

Comment: @DavisHerring There is plausibly some structure. Each data point corresponds to a physical cell, and arguably they were uniformly sampled from their corresponding tissues. That was one intent in the experimental design. The data isn't originally from my university though, and I'm not privy to a ton of details.

Comment: @Hans Musgrave, my guess is that given  background people have in GIS they would 'feel your pain' and have more ideas to help. Of course, it is prudent that you may want to keep topic compliance risk under control.

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak The Meta GIS SE community agrees with you and also suggests that Math SE might be a good fit. Thank you for pointing this out to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I had initially ruled out locally linear embedding and other similar techniques, that seems to have been in haste. Since manifolds are in fact locally linear, a sufficiently well-sampled, sufficiently nice manifold has the property that its **small geodesic distances** are approximately the same as their **corresponding euclidean distances**.

With that in mind, any reconstruction which treats the nearest geodesic neighbors as the nearest euclidean neighbors and approximates the euclidean distance via the geodesic distance will **approximately preserve global geodesic distance**, up to an accumulated error term. This means that all the standard algorithms which only use local distances have the ability to provide an approximately correct embedding. These include and are not limited to

- Locally Linear Embedding
- Isomap
- Spectral Embedding

Some classical embedding algorithms **will not work correctly** in this application since they attempt to preserve all distances, and the large geodesics are probably poor representations of euclidean distance. For example, multidimensional scaling is a poor fit without modifications.

**Note** The reason LLE seemed to yield poor results in my preliminary analysis is that one of my assumptions was violated -- the manifold being sufficiently well-sampled. I was applying it to simple shapes with known desired behavior, but I mistakenly used too few points to ensure a quick feedback loop in my analysis. Better-sampled manifolds behave exactly as they're supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

The fourth chapter of this PhD Thesis

"On Motion Parameterizations in Image Sequences from Fixed Viewpoints", 
Manfred Georg, Washington University, 2010

available: https://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1127&context=etd

discusses some of these problems, with algorithms that depend on if, for example, the manifold is *really* a cylinder (or a cone or something else), and the relative width and length of the cylinder.

Depending on your end goal, alternatives like t-SNE may be a better fit; they drop global geodesic distance constraints entirely, and therefore can be more flexible with shapes like cylinders where it is impossible to embed into a euclidean space and preserve geodesics.

Comment: Your student has neat work, and I'll be looking into it more. For this problem though, we might be talking about different things. I have a set of objects, I know their pairwise geodesics, and I would like to find a euclidean embedding of those objects with the same set of pairwise geodesics. Your answer seems to more closely align with the problem "given a set of objects and their pairwise geodesics, find a euclidean embedding whose pairwise euclidean distances match those pairwise geodesics." Am I misunderstanding?